# why doesnt this animate() jquery function script work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I'm trying to test out how the animate() function works, and this is an example I got from stackexchange actually (it works on fiddle), but when I run it on my local computer, it doesn't work anymore.

Here's the code:

```
<html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts\jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('button').click(function () {
                $('div').animate({
                    width: 'toggle'
                });
            });
            alert("hei");
        });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        div {
            background-color: red;
            height: 100px;
            width: 100px;
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <button>Show/Hide</button>
    <div></div>
</body>
```

Why is this? When I refresh, there's no alert popping up so it's not even processing the javascript I have in there. But it works fine in fiddle.

Oh, and here's the [fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/ddc8G/) But I really don't think it's relevant since it works there, just not on my local computer. Am I missing declaring a library?

Comment: Your jQuery path should use slash instead of backslash. Also, any JS error in console?

Comment: Do you load jQuery correctly?

Comment: working fiddle [http://jsfiddle.net/cCGN7/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/cCGN7/1/)

Comment: Good catch. The console gives me two errors: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost/tests/scripts/jquery-1.11.0.js
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: @akhlesh Working fiddle does not mean no linkage errors in HTML.

Comment: Did your jQuery JS file exist in `scripts/` folder? Probably not.

Comment: I followed your advice and found out I actually had the jquery library in a different folder (this is my test folder I put it in). It's such an easy solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Please change below line :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts\jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
```

with this one :

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
```

You have used **backslash** instead of **slash**

It work For me

Answer (score 1):

I think your jQuery path is not correct you have used

scripts\jquery-1.11.0.js

normally we used `scripts/jquery-1.11.0.js`

Comment: you're right, my path wasn't correct. I've corrected it now.

Answer (score 0):

scripts\jquery-1.11.0.js should be scripts/jquery-1.11.0.js